# How to enforce "no method should use IEnumerable" in an interface?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I have an interface that is used to implement a class that fetches data from Memory Cache:

```
public interface ICacheReader
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees();
    Employee GetEmployeeById(int Id);
}
```

The implementing class's method returns mutable objects like Employee and `IEnumerable<Employee>`, if the any consumer of implementing class changes the data in the returned object, it gets reflected in its origin i.e. Memory Cache.

I want to make sure that data in origin (MemoryCache) should never be updated, no matter what operation is performed on the returned objects.

Should I use IList or List instead of IEnumerable? What should be used instead of Employee for the second method?

We can use more manual methods to make sure prevent this problem, like enforcing Code Review, Analyzer etc.

But I am looking for a solution which will prevent any new method to return mutable objects , Is there any class/interface level single line solution available?

Comment: What does your requirement of a never-updating-cache have to do with using `IEnumerable<T>` in the interface?

Comment: Your problem seems not to be the `IEnumerable` but the fact that `Employee` is mutable.

Comment: ^^ And that can be fixed by making the class immutable or making it a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records) ... depending on further requirements.

Comment: To reinforce Klaus's message - suppose your interface instead had `Employee GetEmployeeById(string)` as a method... you'd have exactly the same problem if someone called that and then modified the object.

Comment: I suspect OP may have it backwards. Sometimes a piece of code will return a `List<T>` but expose it as an `IEnumerable<T>` which expresses to the caller that the "list" is to be treated as read-only, i.e. you can't add or remove items. They might even keep the list itself private by using `foreach yield return`. Is that what you were thinking of @Imran? (This approach does not prevent mutation of the items themselves)

Comment: I just want to put some enforcement so that no one can write a new method signature in this Interface that allows the output to be modified in its origin (memory cache) @JohnWu

Comment: You shouldn't expose mutable types then. It's *really* unclear what you're actually looking for here. You can't stop a method being added to the interface in language terms - but you *can* write unit tests and/or Roslyn analyzers, and impose appropriate code reviews etc. None of this has anything to do with `IEnumerable` though.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet , if I follow Fildor's suggestion (to use record instead of class) will it help?

Comment: @ImranRizvi: Maybe, but we don't really have enough context. If the cache returns a `List<Employee>` then callers could cast back to that - I don't know whether you're deeming that to be a problem or not. Fundamentally while your question focuses on `IEnumerable<T>`, it's going to be hard to provide an answer. But if the cache only returns immutable objects (or copies where necessary - e.g. returning a `List<T>` which is just a snapshot, so modifying it doesn't make any difference), that should be fine...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you , my code is not specific to IEnumerable<T> but any return type which is mutable. I will go ahead with suggestions and few POCs.

Comment: Note that `IEnumerable<T>` itself doesn't provide any mutating members. However, an *implementation* of `IEnumerable<T>` may be mutable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246786/discussion-between-imran-rizvi-and-jon-skeet).